# How to get use details by username in node js with amplify-js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Cognito to authenticate users for a react application that users AWS Lambda to fetch some data. How do I get the details for a specific user by username?

The application is similar to a leaderboard. The users authenticate with cognito and I am storing their name and picture url there. In the react client I need to show specific user's picture and name based on some selection on the client.

I have the usernames stored in a database. Is it possible to make a call to Cognito to get the user details? Or what is the best approach to this? Should I store these details separate from Cognito in a database also? (i.e this seems like duplication of effort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few months ago I had that problem and created this function using AWS-Amplify

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify'
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const CognitoExpress = require('cognito-express')

import { CognitoUserPool, CognitoUser } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'
exports.getUsersFromUserPool = (paramsObject, userPoolRegion) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        AWS.config.update({ 'region': userPoolRegion, 'accessKeyId': process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 'secretAccessKey': process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY })
        var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider()
        cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(paramsObject, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                reject(err)
            }
            else {
                resolve(data)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Then, just call

```
let listInstsParams = {
                        'AttributesToGet': ['email', 'name'],
                        'Filter': 'username= "' + <your_username>+ '"',
                        'UserPoolId': process.env.INSTITUTION_USER_POOL_ID
                    }
 getUsersFromUserPool(listInstsParams, process.env.INSTITUTION_REGION)
                    .then(({ Users }) => console.log(Users))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue and I tried to use the answer of Pedro Silva, but it didn't work for me, until I added the Cognito Endpoint to params:

```js
const fetchCognitoUsers = async(username) => {
  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  require('dotenv/config');

  const awsConfigCognito = {
    region: process.env.region,
    accessKeyId: process.env.accessKeyId,
    endpoint: process.env.endpoint,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.secretAccessKey,
  };
  AWS.config.update(awsConfigCognito);
  var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
  const input = {
    UserPoolId: process.env.USERPOOL_ID, // required
    Filter: `username="${username}"`
  };
  return cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(input).promise();
};

// Later call in the following way:
  const cognitoUser = await fetchCognitoUsers(username);
```

Some relevant documentation can be found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html

In my case my cognito users belonged to a few different cognito groups and because of that I also decided to store more specific information in different DynamoDB tables, which meant that basic attributes were duplicated, but it meant cleaner separation of details.