# Cognito - How to get username from email

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When running the following code

```
const userDetails = {
            Username: email,
            Pool: userPool
        };
const cognitoUser = new amazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userDetails);
console.log(cognitoUser.getUsername());
```

the output is the `email`.

How can I get Cognito user's GUID? (i.e : `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`)

NOTES:

1. The use-case is general and not related to a specific function like 'signup' or 'login'.
2. The only parameter the client pass is an email, (i.e no tokens) for example when users forget their password.

Comment: Please refer the below link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54161981/7895303)

Answer (score 0):

As of today you cannot do it.

The `UUID`/`sub` is an internal attribute. You can search for users having it with the [ListUsers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) API, but you cannot retrieve it in any other way than through a token.